# Change colour of substring from a string

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I want to change color of a particular substring from a post.
eg:-

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempor lacinia urna eget gravida.                      Quisque magna nulla, fermentum fermentum od
#keyword1 #keyword2 #keyword3 #keyword4 #keyword5

if above example is the post then i want to change the style of the keywords. I am using Next.js.

```
 function handleBody(){
var arr1=[],arr2=[];
for(let i=0;i<post.body.length;i++){
    if(post.body[i]==="#"){
      arr1.push(i);
    }
    if(arr1.length!==arr2.length && post.body[i]==" " ){
        arr2.push(i);
    }
}
for(let i=0;i<post.body.length;i++){
  const trial2 =  post.body.substring(arr1[i], arr2[i])
  const trial =  post.body.substring(arr1[i], arr2[i]).style.color ="blue";

  post.body.replace(trial2, trial)
}
return post.body
```

}

I have tried as above but its giving an error

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')